# Quick post to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

There used to be a plugin for Tumblr where you could right click any image and quickly post to, well, Tumblr. It made creating posts on the fly really easy / quick.

Is there something similar in Wordpress?

I have a self-hosted Wordpress.org blog if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings > Writing and check the "Press This" section.

> Press This is a bookmarklet: a little app that runs in your browser
>   and lets you grab bits of the web.
>
> Use Press This to clip text, images and videos from any web page. Then
>   edit and add more straight from Press This before you save or publish
>   it in a post on your site.
>
> Drag-and-drop the following link to your bookmarks bar or right click
>   it and add it to your favorites for a posting shortcut.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. Can't believe it was there the whole time.